Using Set-CASMailbox for employees with an Office 365 F3 license
As employees come on-board or leave the company, I have an app that uses the Powershell Set-CASMailbox cmdlet to enable or disable the mailbox settings in Exchange Online.
If the employee has no license, or they have an E1, E2, or E3 license, it works fine. If they have an F3, the settings are not changed. There is no error issued.
If this is normal behaviour, is it possible to update the app to get the current license and temporarily remove it?
This works as long as there is no F3 license (VB)
Try
    strReturnValue = ConnectToExchangeOnline()
Catch ex As Exception
    strReturnValue = "Error connecting to Exchange Online. Error:   " & ex.Message & vbCr
    Return strReturnValue
End Try

' Clear out the previous commands

gpsShellOnline.Commands.Clear()

' Load the command to set the mailbox

gpsShellOnline.AddCommand("Set-CasMailbox")
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("ActiveSyncEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("EwsEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("Identity", strUserPrincipalName)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("ImapEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("MAPIEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("OWAEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("PopEnabled", False)
gpsShellOnline.AddParameter("SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled", True)

' And execute the command

Try
    gpsResults = gpsShellOnline.Invoke()

Catch ex As Exception
    strReturnValue = "Error disabling e-mail access on-line for " & WindowsUsername & ". Error:   " & ex.Message & vbCr

    Return strReturnValue
End Try

